# how to pass local path to NSXMLParser

Tags: cocoa, nsxmlparser

how to pass local path to `NSXMLParser`

like this

```
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:storePath];
```

where storepath is a local path like this:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/56EEB906-2B73-493C-9BE7-2732440CDB69/Documents/xml1.php
```

and my code is like this:

```
//NSURL *urla = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:storePath];
NSURL *urla = [[[NSURL alloc] init] fileURLWithPath:storePath];

//NSData *dataa = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urla];

NSLog(@"urls ois %@",urla);
```

help me why i am getting null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                     NSDocumentDirectory,
                     NSUserDomainMask, YES
                 );
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *urla = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory
                         stringByAppendingString:@"/xml1.php"]];
```

More details at [iPhone Application Programming Guide: Getting Paths to Application Directories](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW6).

**Update**: There's a common misunderstanding what [`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBJFBGC). It does not replace all whitespace in the string, it only removes leading and trailing whitespace.

If you want to get rid of the spaces, you need to replace them yourself by using something like [`stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:).

However:

- I am not sure what you would replace those strings with to get a valid path. As far as I know, on the simulator the path to the application's Documents folder actually has spaces in it (which accidentally is called out in the document I linked).
- I am not sure why would the spaces bother you. That string is a valid path (as long as you actually have created the `<app>/Documents/xml1.php` file, of course); and according to `NSXMLParser` documentation, [`initWithContentsOfUrl`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001984-BAJCCBCH) accepts any fully qualified URL with scheme supported by `NSURL`, and `file://` is supported scheme.

If there's a particular error the `NSXMLParser` is returning, add it to your question (or ask another one), so we can help you with the actual problem.

Comment: thanks but how to remove those space??

file://localhost/Users/applefan/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/3.1.3/Applications/134C5D58-D930-4F0A-B2F7-D25A170D6F09/Documents/xml1.php

Comment: );
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 documentsDirectory  = [documentsDirectory  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
  NSLog(@"documentsDirectory    is %@",documentsDirectory );

  
  NSURL *urlc = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory
             stringByAppendingString:@"/xml1.php"]];
  
  
  
  //urlc = [urlc stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
  NSLog(@"urls  is %@",urlc);


urlc is still having space plz help

Comment: like this 
ile://localhost/Users/applefan/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/3.1.3/Applications/FD5A8AF3-0B07-4D56-8477-97F0DCEF15B5/Documents/xml1.php

Comment: Hi
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  
 documentsDirectory  = [documentsDirectory  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
  //documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  

  
  NSURL *urlc = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory 
             stringByAppendingString:@"/xml1.php" ]];
  


here my documentdirctly is working fine wihtout any space ,, but when i pass this  to NSurl then i dont know why he is adding those %20 in   between

Comment: RFC 3986 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) specifies the allowed characters in an URL. In particular, space is not included in the set of allowed characters, therefore it needs to be percent-encoded, as per paragraph 2.1 in the same RFC. Hence the `%20`.

Comment: And you still haven't said what exactly is the problem with the spaces or `%20` in the URL. Is `NSURL` or `NSXMLParser` complaining about the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Hey THis all some what not fair.

i suggest this, very simple

```
        NSString *path=@"/Users/farshore/Desktop/prasanna/XMLParsing/Books-6.xml";  //this is ur path of xml file


        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be because you're reading the PHP file directly instead of passing it through PHP so the output isn't XML.